# Link to anchor tag on a different page not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, anchor

I have a link at the bottom of a page, and its purpose is to link to an anchor on a different page. It doesn't seem to work in Firefox (at least, not in v8). Instead, on load it goes right to the very bottom of the page.

Any help is appreciated!

**Source**: http://msi.emsix.com/news/1900/1/Six-in-Ten-Employers-Hope-Health-Care-Reform-will-be-Repealed.aspx (the "Susan McIntyre" link at the bottom)

**Anchor markup**:

```
<h3 id="mcintyre" name="mcintyre">Susan McIntyre</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following code:

```
<a name="mcintyre"></a>
<h3 id="mcintyre">Susan McIntyre</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works correctly if I disable javascript.

It looks like what happens is that the scroll is done before you use script to collapse away a bunch of the content.  So the final scroll position ends up wrong.

If you're collapsing the content away async, that could do it...

Comment: Ah, I think that's what happening. I didn't even consider that it could be a js issue. Thanks! Hmm now I have to think of how to rework this.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know what the problem was because it works correctly on chrome and safari and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to create `<a name='%hashName%'></a>` anchor, consider this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window.location.hash).append('<a name="' + window.location.hash.replace('#','')+ '"></a>');
  window.location.href=window.location.href;
});
```

I know it looks weird, but works fine.

Since today I haven't heard about div anchor tags. Are you sure it is proper to expect such kind of behaviour from browsers?